# Load text file data into data table for specific length scenario

Tags: c#, foreach, text-files

I have a text file which has many irrelevant values and then have values which I have load it into a table. Sample of the file looks like this

```
Some file description date 
C D 8989898989898 some words 

D F 8979797979    some more words

8 H 98988989989898 Some more words for the purpose 

KD978787878                  280000841        1974DIAA                                 EIDER 320   

KK967867668                  280000551        1999OOOD                                 FIDERN 680
```

I can't start from the number of lines because the description part (which is 4 lines, excluding empty line) can be of multi line. Means, it can have up to 40-50 lines per text file.

The only way I can think to pick the data is to select only those rows which has 5 columns and have certain number of space between them.

I have tried it using foreach loop but that didn't work out pretty well. May be I am not able to implement it.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                string[] rows = content.Split('\n');
                foreach (string s in rows)
                {
// how to pick up rows when there are only 5 columns in a row separated by a definite number of space?
                    string[] columns = s.Split('     '); // how to calculate exact spaces here, because space count could be different from one column to the other. Ex: difference between first column and second is 16 and second to third is 8.
                    foreach (string t in columns)
                    {
                       
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of this comes down to massaging and sanitizing the data(yuck!) I would:

1.Use String.Split on content to get all lines(like you did)

```
string[] lines = content.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

2.Parse out empty lines and loop over the result

```
foreach(string line in lines.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Trim())))
```

3.Use String.Split on each line to split out each field for a particular row, stripping white space

```
string[] fields = line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

At this point you can count the number of fields in the row or throw something at each actual field.

Comment: With some more code and tweaks I am able to manage that using your trick. Thanks !!! It really did solve 80% of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal place to use regex to find only lines that fit your needs and even grouping them properly you can get out the trimmed values of the five columns already.
The search expressions seems to be something like "^(K[A-Z0-9]+) +([0-9]+) +([A-Z0-9]+) +([A-Z]+) +([0-9]+) *$" or similar. It helped me a lot in programming to know regex.